# Flat toolbar buttons with Delphi VCL Styles--fixing toolbar items with dropdowns?

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805181/flat-toolbar-buttons-with-delphi-vcl-styles-enabled/16806502#16806502) about making toolbar buttons flat when VCL styles are enabled. Using the solution in that question, now most of my TActionToolbar buttons are flat. However, there's one toolbar button with a drop-down menu with additional actions:

[image]

And it's still drawing button edges around it. How can I remove the button borders for toolbar buttons with drop-downs so they match the other plain buttons, and look more like when VCL styles were disabled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This kind of button is draw by the `TThemedDropDownButton` class, So you must override this class and the `TThemedDropDownButton.DrawBackground` method.

Using the [same unit of the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805181/flat-toolbar-buttons-with-delphi-vcl-styles-enabled/16806502#16806502) add a new class called `TThemedDropDownButtonEx`

```
  TThemedDropDownButtonEx= class(TThemedDropDownButton)
  protected
    procedure DrawBackground(var PaintRect: TRect); override;
  end;
```

Then implement the DrawBackground method like so

```
procedure TThemedDropDownButtonEx.DrawBackground(var PaintRect: TRect);
const
  CheckedState: array[Boolean] of TThemedToolBar = (ttbButtonHot, ttbButtonCheckedHot);
var
  LIndex : Integer;
begin
  LIndex := SaveDC(Canvas.Handle);
  try
    if Enabled and not (ActionBar.DesignMode) then
    begin
      if (MouseInControl or IsChecked or DroppedDown) and
         (Assigned(ActionClient) and not ActionClient.Separator) then
      begin
        StyleServices.DrawElement(Canvas.Handle, StyleServices.GetElementDetails(CheckedState[IsChecked or (FState = bsDown)]), PaintRect);

       if IsChecked and not MouseInControl then
          StyleServices.DrawElement(Canvas.Handle, StyleServices.GetElementDetails(ttbButtonPressed), PaintRect);
      end
      else
        ;
    end
    else
      ;
  finally
    RestoreDC(Canvas.Handle, LIndex);
  end;
end;
```

and Finally modify the *TPlatformVclStylesStyle.GetControlClass* method on this way

Change this code

```
if AnItem.HasItems then
  case GetActionControlStyle of
    csStandard: Result := TStandardDropDownButton;
    csXPStyle: Result := TXPStyleDropDownBtn;
  else
    Result := TThemedDropDownButton;
  end
else
```

by this

```
if AnItem.HasItems then
  case GetActionControlStyle of
    csStandard: Result := TStandardDropDownButton;
    csXPStyle: Result := TXPStyleDropDownBtn;
  else
    Result := TThemedDropDownButtonEx;
  end
else
```

[image]