# Flat Toolbar Buttons with VCL Styles

Tags: delphi

When using VCL Styles, ttoolbuttons appear as 3D even when the parent toolbar has flat:=true. This question is similar to [this question about buttons on tactiontoolbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805181/flat-toolbar-buttons-with-delphi-vcl-styles-enabled/16806502#16806502) and also to [this question pertaining to dropdown buttons on tactiontoolbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842046/flat-toolbar-buttons-with-delphi-vcl-styles-fixing-toolbar-items-with-dropdowns/%22dropdown%20buttons%22). How can I get ttoollbuttons to appear flat? I need the toolbar buttons to be flat both when the button style is tbsbutton and I also need the tbsdropdown style to be flat.

Comment: To modify the toolbar buttons appearance when the *VCL Styles* are active you must  create a new *VCL Style Hook* which descends from the *TToolBarStyleHook* class , then override the *Paint* method and finally register your new Style Hook.